# My sprite continues to keep moving even after releasing the key in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My sprite continues to keep moving even after releasing the key. How can I stop the sprite from moving when I release an arrow key?

This is my Paddle sprite class. Here I gave the paddle a speed and the speed should be added to the sprite when the key is pressed.

```
#Paddle sprite
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((90,20))
        self.image.fill(white)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = (width//2)
        self.rect.bottom = height-15
        self.speedx = 0
     def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5
        self.rect.x+=self.speedx
```

I added all the sprites to a sprite group

```
#All elements of the game
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
paddle = Paddle()
all_sprites.add(paddle)
```

This is the mainloop. I think there's some kind of looping the addition of speed to the sprite but I can't find it.

```py
#Game mainloop
run=True
while run:
    #FPS of gameplay
    clock.tick(fps)

    #Event mainloop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
           run=False

    #Updating all objects in the game
    all_sprites.update()

    #On screen
    wn.fill(black)
    all_sprites.draw(wn)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
run=True
while run:

    #Event mainloop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
           run=False

    #Updating all objects in the game
    all_sprites.update()

    #On screen
    wn.fill(black)
    all_sprites.draw(wn)

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to reset the speed (`self.speedx`), if neither <kbd>LEFT</kbd> nor <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> is pressed:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5

        if not keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 0

        self.rect.x+=self.speedx
```

Because on each update call, the position still gets updated, and since the speed doesn't get reset, it keeps moving in the direction that it had set before.

---

Alternatively the speed can be set 0, at the begin of `update`:

```py
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def update(self):

        self.speedx = 0

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5

        self.rect.x+=self.speedx
```

Comment: Or you could only update the position if either key is pressed, but reseting the value is probably easier to understand.

Comment: @Menotdan Since there is an attribute, which states the current speed, it should be set.

Comment: That's what I mean by "easier to understand", since setting speed to 0 means that the speed of the object is 0

Comment: @Menotdan My point is, that the attribute should state the current speed, maybe it is used for something else later (e.g for some kind of speed or direction display). The attribute should never contain a value which doesn't represent the current state of the object.

Comment: https://youtu.be/px6EoQjkK7c in this video he uses the same code, but his sprites stop moving when the key is released

Comment: @MF8 In the video the first line of update is ` self.speedx = 0`. I've added that to the answer. See the 2nd section.